# How to sign an Elasticsearch index?

Tags: elasticsearch, openssl, signing

**Hi Everyone**

I'm working on log signing. File signing is complete with openssl but I want to sign directories.

Elasticsearch does not store data in a single file. It has a **directory structure**. The image below shows the elasticsearch index directory structure. There are many files here.

[image: elasticsearch index directory structure image]
<sub>(source: [imageupload.net](https://www.imageupload.net/upload-image/2020/01/13/screenshot.png))</sub>

With **Openssl**, I can sign and verify the file. But I would like to sign elasticsearch indices on a daily basis and prove that they were not changed later. But I cannot perform directory signing with Openssl. Elasticsearch has a directory structure. ***So I can't sign elasticsearch index on a daily basis.***

**Can I sign elasticsearch indexes on a daily basis via Openssl or some other way?**

Thank you so much everyone...